# How can I select the region that should be viewed in Word from an embedded spreadsheet object?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, office-for-mac, microsoft-word-2011

Embedding Excel worksheet objects directly into Word seems like a killer feature to me, but it would only be useful for publication if I could choose the "printable area" of the spreadsheet that gets fitted to the frame in Word.  For the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this.  Word only likes to show the first handful of cells in the top left corner.  Resizing the frame just resizes these cells.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Office are you using? How are you pasting these in?

In Office 2003, I can copy an area on a worksheet in Excel and, in Word, select Edit > Paste Special > Paste: > Microsoft Office Excel Worksheet Object.

In this way, I have no limits on the number of cells that appear.

I know definitively that this was a limitation in Office XP, where only a certain number of columns could be displayed.

Comment: +1You also have the choice to paste the area as a link and the content will update.

Comment: This is Word 2011 for Mac.  I already knew I could embed a separate spreadsheet into a Word document (and even make a updatable link as datatoo said).  What I wanted to do was make the spreadsheet only accessible from that document (and not from the filesystem).  This can be done from Word now, but I haven't found a way to control the area displayed.  Word only gives me the choice of showing an icon, or showing an unchangeable region of the spreadsheet.  Paste special doesn't apply because Word 2011 automatically inserts the visible region.